# Ember Data override find method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to override the find() method in ember-data to make it compatible with my app. Its not a huge modification that I have to do, but I don't know where to start.

So far when I try to do this : `this.store.find('enquiry');` Ember-Data is trying to fetch information from `http://localhost/enquiries` instead of `http://localhost/enquiry`. My problem is that I don't need to get the plural of my url..

I thought also using the jquery method but, I would rather using Ember-Data for this. How can I do that ?

Another question : After this is working, is Ember-Data generate dynamically the model in the app ? Because I have a lot field in my JSON and I can't write them down manually...

Can I do something like this :

```
  App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: '-active-model'
  });

  App.Enquiry = DS.Model.extend();
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html) page will show you exactly how to use a custom adapter in your application. And [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html#method_extend) page will show you how to override a method in your subclass.

I didn't see your response on the Ember forum yesterday, but in my opinion, you'd still be better off writing your own adapter. It seems like you're going to do more work trying to modify the REST adapter than if you just created your own.

But if you still want to extend the rest adapter, here is how:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    find: () {
        //...
    }
}):
```

As for your second question, no, Ember-Data will not pick up the fields automatically. I'm pretty sure it'll throw an error if you include fields in your JSON that are not declared in the corresponding model. This is by design. If you don't know your fields at development-time, how can you use them in templates or controllers?

Comment: Thank you! for now I've used `ember.$.get` to fetch my data and I'm doing a for to put it in the store because I'm receiving an array of object (just figure it out). But whenever I refresh my browser the data is deleted in ember-data.. is there any way to deal with that ?

Comment: Yeah, you can store the data in the browser's [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) that will persist through page refreshes.

Comment: You don't need to override `find` to change pluralization.